# MYSQLI Select all where name starts with any number

Tags: mysql

For selecting a name that starts with certain number I use `LIKE 7%` for example, but what about a select statement when searching for a name that starts with any number, a wildcard so to speak?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table  WHERE name LIKE '7%'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name regexp '^[0-9]+'
```